# Does Whirlwind Attack hit unknown invisible creatures within reach?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, invisibility

Does Whirlwind Attack allow you to attack an invisible creature you didn't know was there?

Take a medium fighter (F) under the effects of enlarge person, so they are now large and have a natural reach of 10. He is fighting goblins (G) and somehow two invisible ones (I) have joined the fight behind him without him knowing about them.

```
G · G · G ·
· · · · · ·
· · F F · ·
· I F F · ·
· · · I · ·
· · · · · ·
```

So when the fighter goes to Whirlwind Attack, he first goes to attack the 3 goblins he knows about, but would he be allowed to also attack the two he didn't know about? Whirlwind Attack only seems to care about being within reach. So are the attacks granted and done with concealment or are they denied because you didn't know to attack those squares?

[Whirlwind Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/whirlwind-attack-combat---final)

> **Benefit**: When you use the full-attack action, you can give up your regular attacks and instead make one melee attack at your highest base attack bonus against each opponent within reach. You must make a separate attack roll against each opponent.

Also, would you now know about the invisible creatures?

Comment: Oh, much cleaner battle field than what I had, thanks. I'll keep the dots in mind instead of X's.

Comment: These particular dots are hard to type, but if you search for "unicode middot" in Google there are pages you can copy it from. They do make for a very nice text grid though, don't they?

Comment: Oh much better, and all I have to do is copy your dots. I was using spaces but SE has some funny behaviors for spaces and stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can only attack invisible opponents that you know that exists

You will notice that *Whirlwind Attack* will only hit those who are your **opponents**, meaning that it doesn't work like a fireball and hit everybody inside your reach. Instead, you will hit those you want to hit, your **companions are excluded** from your *Whirlwind Attacks* (unless you want to hit them and declare so).

Likewise, if they know that there is an [invisible opponent](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Invisibility) somewhere near him, he may attempt to hit him, but you roll the d% in secret and only tell him if he missed or hit something.

Invisible creatures have *Total Concealment* agaisnt your attacks.

> **Total Concealment**: If you have line of effect to a target but not line of sight, he is considered to have total concealment from you. **You can't attack an opponent that has total concealment**, though you can attack into a square that you think he occupies.

Comment: "An attack roll represents your attempt to strike your **opponent** on your turn in a round." (http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html) Citation from your answer: "you can attack into a square that you think he occupies" Does it mean that I can attack into each square within my reach with a single Wirlwind attack? I.e. without any evidence of anybody's presence in them.

Comment: You can only attack a square you believe there is something invisible.

Comment: For that, the invisibility special ability gives us a bunch of ways to discover the location of an invisible enemy. http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Invisibility

Comment: @ShadowKras Then shouldn't a creature with the feat Whirlwind Attack convince itself that there's an enemy in every square it threatens just in case? I mean, the creature uses the same amount of resources either way, so why not?

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan That is exactly what I was trying to point at by the quotes. I believe that the player is to decide what the PC thinks, unless the player is using some out-of-game information or the PC is under some mind-affecting effect.

Comment: @HeyICanChan im just going by the rules. If he could do that, i believe the ability would say so. That same logic could be applied to illusions and people would go "well i dont believe it's real".

Comment: Whirlwind doesn`t attack squares, it attacks enemies. But that seems like one thing that will suffer table variation.

Comment: @ShadowKras No. There are two quotes above. One says an atack is always made against an opponent (at least no other valid target is named). The second says an attack into a square is valid. Either we agree that a square can be an opponent, or the term "opponent" cann't be taken literally and the word "opponent" in Whirlwind description is not an argument.

Comment: @Ols im finding trouble looking up what rules allows you to attack squares with melee attacks. I only find references to splash weapons or spells. Know anything you can link me to?

Comment: By the reading of the invisible special ability, you cannot attack an invisible creature's space unless you have detected the presence of this creature with a DC 20 Perception check, which reveals that there is something invisible within 30 ft of your character.

Comment: @ShadowKras "im finding trouble looking up what rules allows you to attack squares with melee attacks." - "If a character tries to attack an invisible creature whose location he has not pinpointed, have the player choose the space where the character will direct the attack." (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Invisibility)

Comment: @ShadowKras "By the reading of the invisible special ability, you cannot attack an invisible creature's space unless you have detected the presence of this creature with a DC 20 Perception check" I don't see why. It says you can attack an invisible creature if you have detected it, I don't see where it says you can't attack if you have not.

Comment: It says you can attack a creature you have detected, which means that if you haven't detected it you cannot attack it. Otherwise there is no point on a DC 20 Perception check and that rule could be removed from the text.